# NRPE 2.15 - check_procs not showing right value

Tags: linux, nagios, nrpe

I've got Nagios Core Version 4.1.0rc2 configured server-side with a client running NRPE 2.15.

I've got the two devices properly communicating using the check_nrpe command, but for whatever reason the Nagios web-portal isn't showing the right value being returned when using check_procs.

Here's the nrpe.cfg from the remote host:

```
command[check_asterisk_proc]=env COLUMNS=500 /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_procs -C asterisk -c 1:
```

Here's the output the check_nrpe command when run from the CLI:

```
/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H 192.168.100.7 -c check_asterisk_proc
PROCS OK: 1 process with command name 'asterisk' | procs=1;;1:;0;
```

But when you look inside the Nagios web-portal, all you see is the following response:

```
asterisk-proc OK    08-04-2015 21:17:27 0d 0h 15m 45s   1/3 NRPE v2.15
```

Another view in the web-portal:

```
Status Information: NRPE v2.15
```

What's throwing it off is that it seems like NRPE is returning it's version number, but not actually running the check_procs command.

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run `check_nrpe` without passing an actual command (e.g., `-c check_procs`), it will reply with the NRPE version number just to indicate that NRPE is working correctly.

(This is helpful if you have multiple NRPE services, and you want to make all of them dependent on a simple NRPE status check.)

The reason you're seeing this in the web interface is that your Nagios conf doesn't match your manual test. Either your service is configured with the wrong `check_command`, or your command definition is doesn't match your usage of it.

The `check_command` in the service definition should resemble `check_nrpe!check_asterisk_proc`, and your command definition for check_nrpe needs to be something like:

```
command_line    /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -c $ARG1$
```

(There may be additional args, like -u, -t 30, etc.)

Comment: I discovered this just about the same time you were writing thing :) Thanks for the help!

Comment: I had this exact same problem, I found that the included command.cfg file that is installed by default is missing the `-c` it reads `command_line $USER!$/check_nrpe -H $HOSTADDRESS$ $ARG1$` but as pointed out above should read `command_line $USER!$/check_nrpe -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -c $ARG1$`

Comment: That's disconcerting. How did you install it? Distro package? From source?